# Excel VBA delete entire row if both columns B and C are blank

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete an entire row in excel if column B and C are blank for that row. I have this vba code that deletes an entire row if the whole row is blank. How can I only delete the row if B and C have no value?

Thank you

```
 Sub DeleteBlank()

 Dim rng
 Dim Lastrow As Integer
 Set rng = Nothing

 Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each i In Range("B1:B" & Lastrow)
    If Application.CountA(i.EntireRow) = 0 Then

        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = i
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, i)
        End If
    End If
Next i
MsgBox (Lastrow)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

--**Update**--

The problem is solved. Thanks to izzymo and sous2817

Here is the current code

```
Sub DeleteBlank()

 Dim i As Integer
 Dim Lastrow As Integer

 Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 MsgBox (Lastrow)
 For i = Lastrow To 2 Step -1
   If Trim(Range("B" & i).Value) = "" And Trim(Range("C" & i).Value) = "" Then
    Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Delete

    End If

  Next i

 MsgBox "Done"

 End Sub
```

Comment: one little nitpick in your solution (other than you're using a loop...look in to using an autofilter instead).  Combine your select and delete row.  Those two rows should be: Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: Thanks sous2817. Could you give me an example?

Comment: posted an example for your consideration.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As asked for, here is a way to do it without looping:

```
Sub NoLoopDelete()
Dim lr As Long

lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With Sheet1.Range("A1:I" & lr)
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="="
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

The results should be the same, but this way *should* be faster, especially if you have a lot of rows.  Obviously, change the column reference to suit your layout and feel free to fancy it up w/ some error checking,etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub DeleteBlank()

 Dim i as Integer
 Dim Lastrow As Integer

 Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Lastrow
    If Trim(Range("B" & i).Value) = "" And Trim(Range("CB" & i).Value) = "" Then
     Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Select
     Selection.Delete
     i = i - 1
    End If

Next i

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: if you go from Lastrow to 2 step -1 you can skip the resetting of your iterator.