# How do I delete entire rows in excel if columns J, K and L are all 0/$0.00?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete entire rows in Excel 2013 but only if all cells in columns K, L and M are 0/$0.00.

Example of my data: 
[Excel Data Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBSIR.png)

I'm wanting it to keep rows 2 - 11 as they all contain something in K, L or M. The current code that I found and have been trying to use seems to only be recognising columns L and M because it is deleting row 2 which has a figure in column K. I don't want it to calculate the totals of the 3 cells in a row because if I have a figure of $500 in column K and -$500 in column L, they'll equal to $0.00 but I need that row because there is data.

I had found 2 questions very similar to what I'm asking on this site so I tried to apply the code to what I'm doing but I must have been doing something wrong because I couldn't get it to work.

[Excel VBA delete entire row if both columns B and C are blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942459/excel-vba-delete-entire-row-if-both-columns-b-and-c-are-blank)

[Delete entire row if cells in specific range are all empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703828/delete-entire-row-if-cells-in-specific-range-are-all-empty)

This is the code that I found and have been trying to use. Could it not be working because 1 column is positive numbers and the other 2 are negative numbers? I'm really new to using VBA etc. so I'm sorry if this is something really simple.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
    Dim N As Long
    For N = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If rng.Cells(N, 1) = 0 And rng.Cells(N, 2) = 0 Then
            rng.Cells(N, 1).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
        End If
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("L1:L" & ActiveSheet.Range("L" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If rng.Cells(N, 1) = 0 And rng.Cells(N, 2) = 0 Then
            rng.Cells(N, 1).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
        End If
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("M1:M" & ActiveSheet.Range("M" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If rng.Cells(N, 1) = 0 And rng.Cells(N, 2) = 0 Then
            rng.Cells(N, 1).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
        End If
    Next N
End Sub
```

The spread sheets that I actually work with and use every day usually contain 12,000 to 15,000 rows (file size is always about 2.5MB). 
I would really appreciate any help on what I could do to make this work. 
Thank you

Comment: You've not set any value to `rng` for Col K.  Also you shouldn't be resetting `rng` like that inside of a loop over rng.Rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRows()
    With ActiveSheet '<--| refer to active sheet (you may want to explicitly refer to a named worksheet: 'With Worksheets("mySheet")')
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(, .UsedRange.Columns.Count).Resize(, 1) '<--| refer to a range in a "helper" column just outside the used range occupying the same rows as your data
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countif(RC11:RC13,0)=3,1,"""")" '<--| use "helper" column to mark "KLM-zero's" rows with a "1", while leaving others with a "blank" mark
            If WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Cells) > 0 Then .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).EntireRow.Delete '<--| delete any row whose "helper" column cell is marked with "1"
            .Clear '<--| clear "helper" column
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Carey.P2820, did you get through it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim rw As Range, r

    'start on the last row
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireRow
        Set rw = .Rows(.Rows.Count)
    End With

    Do While rw.Row > 11
        r = Application.CountIf(rw.Cells(1, "K").Resize(1, 3), 0)
        Set rw = rw.Offset(-1, 0)
        If r = 3 Then rw.Offset(1, 0).Delete
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: my guessing is that he/she has to scan all rows and leave only those with at least one non zero value in columns "K" to "M"